# How to reuse options hash

Tags: ruby, twilio

I am using Twilio Say verbs repeatedly and want to refactor my code. Currently it looks somewhat like this

```
def sample
    render text: (Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
        r.Say 'Welcome to ABC Residence', voice: 'alice', language: 'en-GB'
        r.Say 'Thank you for visiting ABC Residence.', voice:'alice', language: 'en-GB'
        r.Hangup
    end).text
end
```

Notice tht I'm using `voice: 'alice'` and `language: 'en-GB'` twice. How can I put these into a variable to be used over and over again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take them in a hash and use it:

```
def sample
    props = {voice: 'alice', language: 'en-GB'}

    render text: (Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
        r.Say 'Welcome to ABC Residence', props
        r.Say 'Thank you for visiting ABC Residence.', props
        r.Hangup
    end).text
end
```

Comment: I don't think your props hash will be available since it's outside the sample method.  Either move it inside or convert it to a method that returns the hash.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Fixed it now.